# Express.js Static: Content Download Delay

Tags: express, static, delay

I've been searching for a little while on this one. I am building a `express.static()` app for a basic website, but noticed that, for some odd reason, it was taking forever to download the data according to the Dev Tools Net Graph from `localhost`:

http://puu.sh/xyq0R/1e5661d32a.png

It blows my mind that it would take 500ms to load about 45 KB of data, especially when it takes 40 ms to load a 17.1 KB font, but 220 ms for a 1.4 KB small js file (locally of all things!).

The most relevant thing I found was [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2727), but since I'm doing `express.static()`, as far as I know, there's no way to add `setNoDelay(true)`. Someone also mentioned something about Regis, but that had to do with `setNoDelay(true)` and the Nagle method. Also, the user in that issue is using an SSD but has similar times to me with my HDD.

To mention, I have tried this on Heroku with an already running server and got the same times.

I'm kind of lost on search terms and relevant pages to look at. I know it has something to do with express based upon what I read, but I'm lost beyond that.

**Update:**

Trying to put `setNoDelay(true)` as a separate middleware before `express.static()` still does not work. I am getting the same times. Reference:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  req.connection.setNoDelay(true);
  next();
});

app.use('/', express.static('./src'));
```

Comment: Does your local hard drive go to sleep ever?

Comment: @jfriend00 It does, but I also just tested it on Heroku (which I will add onto the main post) and it has the same issue. The linked GitHub issue has the same problem on an SSD.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2727#issuecomment-128914887) explains how to use the `setNoDelay(true)` middleware fix which will work with `express.static()` too.  You just need to put the `setNoDelay` middleware as the first middleware (before `express.static()`).

Comment: @jfriend00 Just tried it like so 
`app.use('/', function(req,res,next){ req.connection.setNoDelay(true); 
next();
}, express.static('./src'));` to no avail. Times are the same. http://puu.sh/xys0K/18041f486f.png

Comment: That's not the proper implementation.  You don't want a path at all on your `app.use()` because that limits the middleware to ONLY that path so it will never be used on your static files.  The comment I linked for you show the exact correct implementation and you MUST put it as the very first middleware before `express.static()`.